# Google APP MAKER - Function Server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Tengo un problema, estoy comenzando a trabajar con google APP MAKER. 
Creé un script de servidor. Dentro del script he definido una función...

```
function createPedido_(){ 
    var pedido = app.models.Pedidos.newRecord();
    pedido.Id_pedido= generateNextPedidoId_();
    pedido.Ped_Fecha_Ingreso = new date();
    // pedido.Yacimiento = yaci; 
    pedido.Owner = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
    app.saveRecords([pedido]); 
    return pedido;
}
```

========================================================================

Esta función la quiero invocar desde un botón de una página, en el evento onClick, desde Custom action, pero no veo que me aparezca para seleccionar la función que he definido.

Alguien me podrá indicar si para poder invocar funciones de este tipo debo configurar algún parámetro?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder invocar una función de servidor, es necesario usar el servicio de `google.script.run`; De manera que lo que tenés que hacer es poner el siguiente código en el **onClick** del botón.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(respuesta){
    //lógica a implementar en caso de éxito
}).withFailureHandler(function(error){
    //lógica a implementar en caso de error
}).createPedidio_();
```